How to insert a pagebreak after the ToC, LoT or LoF?
How can I have a pagebreak after the table of contents, table of figures, or table of tables in quarto, when I render as pdf?
I tried using the before-body.tex file and include a \pagebreak, however it puts it between the title and the TOC.
Here is a MWE of the quarto document:
---
title: Untitled
format:
  pdf:
    toc: true
    lof: true
author: Author
date: last-modified
---

# Title 1 

Some text

# Title 2

# Title 2.1

![This is a figure][example.png]


You could use another class, like scrbook which treats these lists as chapters.

Isn't inserting \pagebreak before # Title 1 doing what you want?

@Jan yes it does ! Thanks a lot, I thought it would be more complex

You are welcome. Shall I write this as an answer or are there more open topics if one uses this?

No, I think you can write it as an answer since the main issue is fixed. Thanks !

You can insert the \pagebreak before the # Title 1. This will insert a page break after the list of figures (in the corresponding .tex a \pagebreak is inserted after the \maketitle).
---
title: Untitled
format:
  pdf:
    toc: true
    lof: true
author: Author
date: last-modified
---

\pagebreak

# Title 1 

Some text

# Title 2

# Title 2.1

![This is a figure][example.png]


